# Passing data back to previous callback with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to scrape a film sharing site, where each film can have multiple episode. The spider still works fine, but there are some drawback with the returned items.

When the spider access the index page, it will extract links to view film(http://tamnhinso.info/phim/phim-bo/), then it will yield request to get the show page for films(which have many episodes), from there it's gonna parse the link for each episode, then try to yield a GET request to each episode URL. After that, the spider will parse the HTML response to get the video link for each episode.

```py
def start_requests(self):
      for url in self.start_urls:
        yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_list_movie)

    def parse_list_movie(self, response):
      movie_urls = LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='col-md-2 col-xs-6 movie-item']").extract_links(response)
      for item in movie_urls:
        yield Request(url=item.url, callback=self.parse_movie_info)

      next_page = response.meta.get('next_page')
      num_next_page = 2 if next_page is None else next_page
      next_page_link = "phim/phim-bo/viewbycategory?page="

      if num_next_page <= 40:
        yield response.follow(next_page_link + str(num_next_page), 
                      callback=self.parse_list_movie, meta = {'next_page' : num_next_page + 1})

    def parse_movie_info(self, response):
      l = ItemLoader(item=PhimBoItem(), response=response)
      #some code to retrieve information from that film

      link_film_url = response.xpath("//div[@class='movie-detail']//div[@class='mt-10']/a/@href").extract_first()
      yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(link_film_url), callback=self.parse_list_episode, meta={"item": l})


    def parse_list_episode(self, response):
        loader = response.meta.get('item')
        script = """
                function main(splash)
                    splash.html5_media_enabled = true
                    splash.private_mode_enabled = false
                    assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
                    assert(splash:wait(3))
                    return splash:html()
                end
            """
        for episode in LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='col-md-6 mt-20 watch-chap']").extract_links(response):
            yield SplashRequest(url=response.urljoin(episode.url), callback=self.parse_link_episode, meta={'item': loader}, endpoint='execute',
                                    args={'lua_source': script,'wait': 5, 'timeout': 3600})

    def parse_link_episode(self, response):
      loader = response.meta.get('item')
      loader.replace_value('episode', self.get_episode(response))
      return loader.load_item()

    def get_episode(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=Episode(), response=response)
        l.add_value('ep_num', response.url, re = r'\-(\d+)')
        l.add_value('link', self.get_link(response))
        return dict(l.load_item())


    def get_link(self, response):
      l = ItemLoader(item=Link(), response=response)
      l.add_xpath('link_360', "//source[@label='360']/@src")
      l.add_xpath('link_720', "//source[@label='720']/@src")
      l.add_xpath('link_1080',  "//source[@label='1080']/@src")

      return dict(l.load_item())
```

The item returned will get passed through item pipelines and save in json line format. As each film has many episodes, the result I get is like this:

```
{"id":1, ..., "episode": {"ep_num": "1", "link": "..."}}
{"id":1, ..., "episode": {"ep_num": "2", "link": "..."}}
{"id":2, ..., "episode": {"ep_num": "1", "link": "..."}}
```

that because the items pass to the pipelines is the data for each episode in a film. 
I want the data look like this:

```
{"id":1, ..., "episode": [{"ep_num": "1", "link": "..."}, 
                           {"ep_num": "2", "link": "..."}, ...]}
{"id":2, ..., "episode": {"ep_num": "1", "link": "..."}}
```

I guess I need to pass the data back to previous callback in scrapy, but I don't find out how to do it. Please help me out. I really appreciate that. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I am aware there is at least no easy way to gather those responses within your parse method.

The simplest way might be to post process your items after your crawl finished.

If you can't wait that long you could pass a list of requested URLs as meta data with each request. In your item pipeline you could try to wait for all those responses until you do further processing. In that case you would have to ensure that really all requests produce an item (even those which failed or are dropped).

EDIT: I just stumbled upon this lib. It might help you: https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests

Comment: Thank you, I'm checking this library out. Whenever I find a sollution to my problem, I will post it here. Thanks a lot!